# Javascript regex fail

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string output of the following format :

```
mp3 @ 0x75b225b8]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[lavf] stream 0: audio (mp3), -aid 0
[lavf] stream 1: video (mjpeg), -vid 0, 

Clip info:
 Release date: Songspk.LINK
 album_artist: Various Artists
 album: Kapoor & Sons (Since 1921)
 artist: Tanishk Bagchi, Arijit Singh & Asees Kaur

 composer: Amaal Mallik | Songspk.LINK
 disc: 1/1
 encoded_by: Lame
 genre: Bollywood Music
 title: Bolna - Songspk.LINK
 track: 1/1
 EpisodeID: Songspk.LINK
 copyright: Songspk.LINK
 TOPE: Amaal Mallik | Songspk.LINK
 TIT1: Songspk.LINK
 TIT3: Songspk.LINK
```

And I need to extract the following fields :

```
album: Kapoor & Sons (Since 1921)
artist: Tanishk Bagchi, Arijit Singh & Asees Kaur
```

I tried the following but cannot extract the fields :

```
if(data.indexOf('album:') !== -1) {
    this.artist = data.match(/artist: ([^']*)/)[1];
}
```

EDIT :
The closest I could get is with this :

```
/Clip info:\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*)/
```

Dumping out the entire object it looks good.

```
[ ' artist: Tanishk Bagchi, Arijit Singh & Asees Kaur', 
  'Tanishk Bagchi, Arijit Singh & Asees Kaur', 
  index: 105, 
  input: 'Clip info:\n Release date: Songspk.LINK\n album_artist: Various Artists\n album: Kapoor & Sons (Since 1921)\n artist: Tanishk Bagchi, Arijit Singh & Asees Kaur\n composer: Amaal Mallik | Songspk.LINK\n disc: 1/1\n encoded_by: Lame\n' ]
```

But on trying to reference index 1 I get TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null.

Comment: `/artist:(.*?)\n/`

Comment: Thanks. I tried /artist: (.*)/ and that seemed to work too.

Comment: might be helpful for debugging regex'es: http://regexr.com/

Comment: What do you get? An empty string? An error? The latter might be because you are trying to access position 1 in the returned array, instead of position 0.

Answer (score 1):

Got it `/artist: (.*)/` seems to work

Comment: Actually scratch that .. that seems to capture album_artist instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the following but cannot extract the fields :
>   `if(data.indexOf('album:') !== -1) {
>       this.artist = data.match(/artist: ([^']*)/)[1];
>   }`

The issue is that you are using a **negated character class** `[^']` that matches *any character but `'` incl. a newline*, while you need to match the rest of the *line* after the word "artist" that appears right at the beginning of a line.

I believe you could use

```
^ artist: (.*)
```

Or - to allow any 1+ *horizontal* whitespaces at the start  of the line followed with `artist:` and then followed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces, use

```
^[^\S\r\n]+artist:[^\S\r\n]*(.*)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wE1aK7/1)

The class `[^\S\r\n]` matches any character that is not a non-whitespace and not a CR and not an LF.

Comment: That seems to work. Smthing abt doing this in node.js that I dont seem to grasp. Dumping out the entire object it looks good.  

[ ' artist: Tanishk Bagchi, Arijit Singh & Asees Kaur',
  'Tanishk Bagchi, Arijit Singh & Asees Kaur',
  index: 105,
  input: 'Clip info:\n Release date: Songspk.LINK\n album_artist: Various Artists\n album: Kapoor & Sons (Since 1921)\n artist: Tanishk Bagchi, Arijit Singh & Asees Kaur\n composer: Amaal Mallik | Songspk.LINK\n disc: 1/1\n encoded_by: Lame\n' ]
But on trying to reference index 1 I get TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null. Plus 1 for the regex.

Comment: That issue means you did not get a match. Make sure you run a regex against  a *string*, not an object. Also, if it is a valid JSON, you could just use a JSON parser instead of regex.

Comment: It seems like a mixed object to me and not JSON.